# The best triple of Z is the set of three distinct indices i, j, and k, with i≤j≤k, that makes the product Z[i]*Z[j]*Z[k] as large as possible

Tags: algorithm

am asked to solve a problem using divide and conquer .
the problem says :Let Z is array of n + integers, n≥3. The best triple of Z is the set of three distinct indices i, j, and k, with i<j<k, that makes the product Z[i]*Z[j]*Z[k] as large as possible.
any ideas how can i solve this problem using divide and conquer.
any ideas how can i solve this ?

Comment: Do you have negative values in the array?

Comment: @SomeDude  i know i can get the max 3 times but i am asking if there any other way using D&C without find the max and sorting the array .

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be done only using Divide and Conquer here is one approach I could think of other than the one mentioned in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961782/1410303) about selection using Divide and Conquer.

You need to first solve :

- the maximum value in an array , lets call this:

*maximum(arr, start, end )*

- the maximum product of two elements. Lets call this method:

*maxTwoProduct(arr, start, end)*

This can be solved using Divide and Conquer as well like:

```
int maxTwoProduct(arr, start, end):
   if ( end - start + 1 < 2 ):
      return MIN_VALUE
   int mid = (end+start)/2;
   max_11 = maximum(arr, start, mid);
   max_12 = maxTwoProduct(arr, start, mid);
   max_21 = maximum(arr, mid+1, end);
   max_22 = maxTwoProduct(arr, mid+1, end);
   return Math.max(max_11*max_21, max_12, max_22)
```

The idea is you divide the array into two parts, the *maxTwoProduct* could occur in one of the following ways:

- The max product can be entirely in left part
- The max product can be entirely in right part
- The max product can be a product of maximum value in left part and maximum value in right part

This can be extended to the *maxThreeProduct* as well like below:

```
int maxThreeProduct(arr, start, end):
   if ( end - start + 1 < 3 ):
      return MIN_VALUE
   int mid = ( end + start ) / 2;
   maximum_11 = maximum(arr, start, mid);
   maximum_12 = maxTwoProduct(arr, start, mid);
   maximum_13 = maxThreeProduct(arr, start, mid);
   maximum_21 = maximum(arr, mid+1, end);
   maximum_22 = maxTwoProduct(arr, mid+1, end);
   maximum_23 = maxThreeProduct(arr, mid+1, end);
   return Math.max( maximum_11*maximum_22, maximum_12*maximum_21, maximum_13, maximum_23);
```

The max here can be one of the following four choices:

- The maximum three product can occur entirely in left half
- It can occur entirely in right half
- It can be product of *maxTwoProduct* in left half and maximum value
  in right half
- It can be product of *maxTwoProduct* in right half and maximum value
  in left half

Comment: That's a nice solution. I guess that's what was expected by the original author of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort the array to find the greatest, second-greatest and third-greatest elements. You can use a D&C `O(n)` [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

It's also worth noting out that finding the three greatest elements can be done with a naive algorithm with `O(3n) = O(n)` complexity.

Comment: Get three pairs (ind, val) and sort them by ind. 3 comparisons.